# Traefik v2 with Docker shows 404 page not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Here are the files

```
# Dockerfile.traefik

FROM traefik:v2.3

COPY ./traefik.prod.toml ./etc/traefik/traefik.toml
```

```
# Dockerfile.prod

FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app
#
COPY . /app

# set env variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# 
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN chmod 600 /app/traefik-public-certificates/acme.json
```

```
# traefik.prod.toml

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.web.http]
    [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
        to = "websecure"
        scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[accessLog]

[api]
dashboard = true

[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    exposedByDefault = false

[certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme]
  email = "myemail@domain.com"
  storage = "/certificates/acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "web"
```

```
# docker-compose.prod.yml

version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    tty: true
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      - LHMS_SECRET
      - LHMS_ALGORITHM
      - LHMS_KEY
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi.rule=Host(`fastapi.canyoutest.me`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "traefik.port=80"
    networks:
      - traefik-public     

  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - TRAEFIK_CERTIFICATESRESOLVERS_LE_ACME_STORAGE=/certificates/acme.json
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik-public-certificates:/certificates"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`dashboard-fastapi.canyoutest.me`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"    
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"      
    networks:
      - traefik-public     
volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates:
  certificates:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

Finally, I issue

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up -d --build
```

the two containers are up and running:

this works: `https://dashboard-fastapi.canyoutest.me/dashboard/#/`

**this doesn't work** and results with 404 page not found: `https://www.fastapi.canyoutest.me/docs`

Ports opened on the ubuntu server:

```
State         Recv-Q        Send-Q                 Local Address:Port                  Peer Address:Port        Process        
LISTEN        0             4096                         0.0.0.0:80                         0.0.0.0:*                          
LISTEN        0             4096                   127.0.0.53%lo:53                         0.0.0.0:*                          
LISTEN        0             128                          0.0.0.0:22                         0.0.0.0:*                          
LISTEN        0             4096                         0.0.0.0:443                        0.0.0.0:*                          
LISTEN        0             511                        127.0.0.1:45959                      0.0.0.0:*                          
LISTEN        0             4096                            [::]:80                            [::]:*                          
LISTEN        0             128                             [::]:22                            [::]:*                          
LISTEN        0             4096                            [::]:443                           [::]:*
```

I run custom-api with `fastAPI` and using DO droplet ubuntu server. `canyoutest.me` is a testing domain and all the DNS A records are created and pingable.

Some ideas/advice on what's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your python container doesn't have any entrypoint and thus theres no webserver traefik can route to.

Try adding a entrypoint to your container like so (if you use uvicorn you can use any webserver you like)

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Comment: Yes, that was the missing line of code in the Dockerfile. Thank you :)